# How to equally distribute the width of QSplitter

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I have a problem with adjusting width of `QSplitter`. I prepared UI in Qt Designer and it looks now like that:

**Designer view**:

[image]

And here is my **object inspector**:

[image]

My question is how to divide the width of `QSplitter` equally over the left and right area. I would like to get this effect as initial size and then the customer can do whatever he wants.

**Effect which I would like to have is the following:**

[image]

In other worlds, I am looking for a way to specify the splitter initial division of left and right area as 50%/50% of window width. Is there any option to obtain that?

Thank you for your help and please be forgiving, I have just started to learn Qt.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Short answer

```
splitter->setSizes(QList<int>({INT_MAX, INT_MAX}));
```

*Note:* The fine tuning section may contain essential information if you want other ratios.

### Explanation

#### `QSpacer`? No.

You do not need a `QSpacer` in this case. The goal of a spacer is to fill all available space.

`QSplitter` provides two methods to specify the size of its children:

#### 1. [`QSplitter::setStretchFactor`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#setStretchFactor)? No.

Although the **stretch factor** may seem to be what you are looking for to specify the relative size of the child widgets, it has the disadvantage for your case that the factors are relative to the initial size of the child widgets:

> *stretch* is not the effective stretch factor; the effective stretch
> factor is calculated by taking the initial size of the widget and
> multiplying it with *stretch*.

Therefore, setting the stretch factor for both children to the same value (ex. `1`) will not work well:

```
splitter->setStretchFactor(0, 1);
splitter->setStretchFactor(1, 1);
```

#### 2. [`QSplitter::setSizes`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#setSizes)? Yes.

A better alternative is to use **`setSizes`**, because only the relative sizes matter:

> The overall size of the splitter widget is not affected. Instead, any
> additional/missing space is distributed amongst the widgets according
> to the relative weight of the sizes.

So, one could think that setting both sizes to one will distribute the total size equally over both children:

```
splitter->setSizes(QList<int>({1, 1}));
```

No, because you should take into account that the minimal size policy will be enforced by replacing too small values with their minimal size:

> The size policies of the widgets are preserved. That is, a value
> smaller than the minimal size hint of the respective widget will be
> replaced by the value of the hint.

So, you should use a value that is greater than the minimal size of your children, for example the greatest number that can be represented with an `int`, i.e. `INT_MAX`:

```
splitter->setSizes(QList<int>({INT_MAX, INT_MAX}));
```

### Fine tuning

As suggested in the comments, `INT_MAX` may result in some overflow issues, depending on the calculations Qt does with those values. This may be especially the case if you want a non-equal distribution ratio. Therefore, a more sensible large value may be the desktop width/height.

```
// Horizontal splitter
int largeWidth = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen ()->virtualSize ().width ();
splitter->setSizes(QList<int>({largeWidth , largeWidth}));

// Vertical splitter
int largeHeight = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen ()->virtualSize ().height ();
splitter->setSizes(QList<int>({largeHeight , largeHeight}));
```

### Further reading

Most of the time, Qt does a good job giving all widgets an appropriate size, but tweaking it can become very hard requiring some trial and error. Therefore I want to provide some extra resources which may be useful when working with layout management in Qt:

- [Qt documentation about layout management](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)
- [A nice summary of layout management in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4672493/7621674)
- Example: [Using multiple `QLayout` items to draw a calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43285029/7621674)

Comment: I would not recommend use INT_MAX in context of QSplitter sizes. In some cases it works well, in some don't. If you want to maximize one part and minimize another, using QList<int>({INT_MAX, 1}) will not work. Because it calls qGeomCalc in qlayoutengine.cpp, and there "int sumStretch" variable that calculates the sum of stretch factors. With huge numbers like INT_MAX it could overflow and produce wrong result.

Comment: @Vladislav, What do you suggest? Is it a problem when all the values are set to INT_MAX? If you try to maximize one part and minimize the other, isn't setting [`QSizePolicy::Policy`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum) (to `Maximum`/`Preferred` and `MinimumExpanding` respectively) more appropriate?

Comment: Imagine splitter for 2 widgets. If you setSizes({INT_MAX, INT_MAX}) it split into 2 equal pieces. If you setSizes({INT_MAX, 1}) - it also split into 2 equal pieces. If you call setSizes({99999, 1}) - it will maximize the first widget and minimize the second. About SizePolicy, yes it is more appropriate solution, but if you called once QSplitter::setSizes() method, after that splitter will not react on SizePolicy changes.

Answer (score 6):

Based on [m7913d's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43835396/1204611)

To equally divide a splitter use `QSplitter::setSizes`, each size in the list should be equal. Use `QWidget::minimumSizeHint()` to determine the size to use. Use the maximum width (for horizontal splitters) or the maximum height (for vertical splitters) of every widget you added to the splitter

```
// Example for a horizontal splitter
splitter = new QSplitter(Qt::Horizontal, this);
splitter->addWidget(widgetLeft);
splitter->addWidget(widgetRight);
auto equalWidth = std::max(widgetLeft->minimumSizeHint().width(), 
                           widgetRight->minimumSizeHint().width());
splitter->setSizes({ equalWidth, equalWidth });
```

```
// Example for a vertical splitter
splitter = new QSplitter(Qt::Vertical, this);
splitter->addWidget(widgetTop);
splitter->addWidget(widgetBottom);
auto equalHeight = std::max(widgetTop->minimumSizeHint().height(),
                            widgetBottom->minimumSizeHint().height());
splitter->setSizes({ equalHeight, equalHeight });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a further variation. The points of m7913d all hold and are important. But in my case (Qt5.13.2) I found that setting large enough sizes could *still* lead to some variations. I do not know why exactly but setting all the stretch factors to one *additionally* finally behaved like I wanted.

Also note that setting all stretch factors to one but using non-equal (but still large enough to avoid minimum size constraints) sizes with `setSizes` works, too! For example:

```
splitter->setStretchFactor(0,1);
splitter->setStretchFactor(1,1);
splitter->setSizes({static_cast<int>(10000 / 1.618), static_cast<int>(10000 - 10000 / 1.618)});
```

sets a golden ratio split.

Comment: Note that this also does not seem to be stable, it is just more stable. In my code, I had to tolerate quite some jumps... No clue why Qt solves it so badly